# Value of strings different, but printing them shows the same value

Tags: c++, c, strcmp, stat

I am running the following code to check if a file exists or not, but when passing the string to stat, it return fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main ()
{
struct stat statbuf;
char tmp_buf1[100];
char result [100];
char result1[100]="/root/file.sh";
strcpy(tmp_buf1,"echo $HOME/file.sh");
FILE* fp;
fp = popen(tmp_buf1,"r");
printf("Name passed is:%s\n",tmp_buf1);
fread(result,1,sizeof(result),fp);
fclose (fp);
printf("The full path is  %s\n",result);
int rc = 0;

// To find out difference b/w the the strings, I am doing a strcmp, it is returning 10.
int r = strcmp(result,result1);

printf (" Return is = %d\n",r);
rc = stat(result, &statbuf);
if ( rc == -1 ) {
    printf("File is NOT HERE!\n");
    printf("Return Code = %d",rc);
   }
else
    printf("Found it !");
}
```

Not sure how come these strings are not same.

Comment: Are you running as root? What do the strings say when you `printf()` them (or in debugger) ?

Comment: What does `fread` return? Also, if a function fails (like `stat`) the error is in `errno`.

Comment: Oh another thing, please include the actual output from the program in the question.

Comment: Print the strings in a way so you can see spaces around them, e.g., using `printf("value='%s'", value);`. I'm pretty sure the string read from the file contains an extra newline character. You might want to read the content using `fgets()` insteat of `fread()`.

Comment: Output:Name passed is:echo $HOME/file.sh
The full path is  /root/file.sh

 Return is = 10
File is NOT HERE!

Comment: stat is returning ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Probably, your return buffer in `result` has a newline character in the end. See the tip of @DietmarKühl to find out.

Comment: try initializing result[] to nulls (memset(result,0,sizeof(result));

Answer (score 3):

```
strcpy(tmp_buf1,"echo $HOME/file.sh");
```

`echo` ends the string it shall echo with a newline `'\n'`, ASCII code 10. That's the difference between the two strings. Try it with

```
strcpy(tmp_buf1,"echo -n $HOME/file.sh");
```

On another note, a `FILE*` opened with `popen` ought to be closed with `pclose`, not with `fclose`.

Comment: echo -n $HOME/file.sh worked !!. But in the real use case this is dynamic. Not sure how to make it work there

Comment: You can also check whether the `echo`ed string ends with a newline, and if so, overwrite that with `'\0'` in the buffer.